# Multiple arraylist into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#

Hello I was wonder if there was any ways  I could merge multiple arraylist into a multi array.

Exmaple

I have arraylist1 which holds names.  arraylist 2 which holds phone number and arraylist 3 which holds address.  how could i merge these into one multi array so it would be as a record?

Comment: What version of .NET (helps me know whether you could utilize LINQ or not, also whether you have access to List<T> instead of ArrayList)?

Comment: The the arrays in the same order? What I mean is, is the Names[0] = PhoneNumbers[0] = Addresses[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose you have three ArrayList of string and all elements at `ith` index forms a record,

```
ArrayList Names = new ArrayList();
ArrayList Phone = new ArrayList();
ArrayList Address = new ArrayList();
ArrayList res = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0; i<Names.Count; i++)
{
  res.Add(new string[]{Names[i].ToString(), Phone[i].ToString(), Address[i].ToString()});
}
```

Comment: you could also do a new object[] or a new class or struct to hold each composite member so you don't have to handle "stringification".

Comment: How do i get the informaiton out of the arraylist though?

Comment: To get back the values type cast it to string[].

Answer (score 1):

Are the contents of these ArrayLists related in some way, such as contacts?

If so, consider creating a class to represent a single contact.  This contact class can have Name, PhoneNumber, and Address properties.  You can even use a collection for each of these properties in case more than one would apply to a given contact record.

You can store your different contact records into an ArrayList, or if you're using .NET 2+ a strongly typed List.

Comment: +1 for mentioning actually creating an object to represent the three fields. C# is an object-oriented language... why not use it as such?

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating in .NET 4.0 you should use `List<T>` though you could still do this with `ArrayList` too if you like.  But you could take advantage of the `Tuple` to combine your types easily (though I totally agree with the suggestions to create a custom class to hold the "record"):

```
    List<string> phones = new List<string>();
    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    // fill with data

    List<Tuple<string,string,string>> results = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    // aggregate with data - if only two you could also use Zip()
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
        results.Add(Tuple.Create(names[i], addresses[i], phones[i]));
    }
```

Comment: question, how do i get the info out of the Arraylist, since it seems to be in a multi type list?