# How to get data out of an Arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist

So in a [previous quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206058/multiple-arraylist-into-a-multi-dimensional-array) I asked how i could merge multiple array list into one array list.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206058/multiple-arraylist-into-a-multi-dimensional-array/6206133#6206133) worked (also listed below). However, I am having issues getting the records out.  How do I get the data out of this multi dimensional arraylist.  For example, what if I wanted to get just address out?

```
ArrayList Names = new ArrayList(); 
ArrayList Phone = new ArrayList(); 
ArrayList Address = new ArrayList(); 
ArrayList res = new ArrayList();  
for(int i=0; i<Names.Count; i++) 
{   
  res.Add(new string[]{Names[i].ToString(), Phone[i].ToString(), Address[i].ToString()}); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` in the first place? It's practically obsolete since .net 2.0 (replaced by `List<T>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like the following ... I want to make sure and I note that you might want to come up with better data structures or container classes if you can.

```
string someAddress = ((string[])res[0])[2];
```

In this instance we are taking the object (string array) at the first index of `res` and then indexing into the string array where the address was stored.

You could consider a something like the following though to contain your data with a typed list..

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Not Me", Phone = "(555) 212-1234", Address = "123 Fake St." });

string address = people[0].Address;
```

Comment: So i tried this idea and it still doesn't work. I am grabing my values from a notes database. So for instance to get the address into a string var i need to do this string addr = ((object[])(doc.GetItemValue("Address")))[0].ToString(); In order for it to go into a var. It won't let me put it int that list.                                                               e.g  people.Add(new Person() { Address = ((object[])(doc.GetItemValue("Address")))[0].ToString() });                   doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make this a struct.

```
public struct Record
{
  public String Name;
  public String Telephone;
  public String Address;
}
```

And push the information in to the structs and then re-reference them. Something like:

```
ArrayList records = new ArrayList();
for (...) {
  records.Add(new Record(){
    Name = Names[i].ToString(),
    Telephone = Phone[i].ToString(),
    Address = Address[i].ToString()
  });
}
...
Console.WriteLine(records[0].Address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is .NET 2.0 and not anything later so you have to stick with `ArrayList`, I would just introduce a new class to hold your information.

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public Person(string name, string phone, string adress)
    {
        _name = name;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can populate instances of this class in your arraylist and access its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you are creating array lists like you are?  In my opinion, you're better off to create a custom object that has 3 properties -> Name, Phone and Address, and simply create a list of those objects:

Resident class:

```
public class Resident
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
List<Resident> residents = new List<Resident>();
// populate list

foreach (var res in residents)
  Console.WriteLine(res.Address);
```

Comment: We tried to mention that in the "previous question" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206058/multiple-arraylist-into-a-multi-dimensional-array), but he seems forced to use arraylist (or just hell-bent on using one).

Comment: Definitely was an interesting approach.  I can say that I have never seen that before :)